# Change string to JSON in minimal API

Tags: .net, sql-server, flutter, api, asp.net-web-api

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create minimal API, I post the link generate in swagger to Postman turned out the result was in string not JSON, how to solve this?

```
app.MapPost("/Service", (Service person) =>
{
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand(
    $"INSERT INTO Service ( servicename, description, category,initialprice,IntermediatePrice,AdvancedPrice) VALUES ('{person.ServiceName}','{person.Description}','{person.Category}','{person.InitialPrice}','{person.IntermediatePrice}','{person.AdvancedPrice}')",
    conn);

    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
})
.WithName("CreateService");
app.MapGet("/Result", () =>
{
    var rows = new List<string>();
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 100 A.DR_PI_000_01 AS drainage_id,MAX(A.DR_PI_000_03) AS latest_time \r\nFROM DR_PI_000 A\r\n\r\nGROUP BY A.DR_PI_000_01", conn); 
        command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rows.Add($"Drainage_ID: {(reader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : reader?.GetString(0))},date : {(reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader?.GetDateTime(1))},");


        }
    }

    return rows;
})
.WithName("GetResult");
```

This snippet is from my program.cs. I don't want to use dbcontext because the table in SQL Server has too many columns, I want to use few only.

Comment: That code looks like it's open to Injection attacks.

Comment: Obligatory reference to [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). For the love of dog please learn to use parameterized queries by way of [`SqlParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types). Also, `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` classes, your code is going to be leaking connections like a sieve.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to JSON in Flutter's minimal API, you can use the **jsonDecode** function provided by the **dart:convert** library. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import 'dart:convert';

// Assuming you have a string containing JSON data
String jsonString = '{"name": "John", "age": 30}';

void main() {
  // Convert the string to JSON
  var json = jsonDecode(jsonString);

  // Access the JSON values
  String name = json['name'];
  int age = json['age'];

  // Print the values
  print('Name: $name');
  print('Age: $age');
}
```